# How to achieve stateful fail over when using multiple uplinks?

Tags: routing, load-balancing, linux-networking, failover

I have multiple ISP lines over which I am load balancing the network traffic on my linux machine having multiple interfaces ( eth0, eth1 ,eth2, eth3) . This I am doing by creating the routing tables and the rules that apply to them.

Connections get distributed according to these rules and balancing of network traffic is achieved. Fail over is my concern now. In case one of the link fails, all established connections on it are lost and need to be re-established. This is not what I wish .I want these connections to move onto the other active links, without having the need to be re-established, in case of link failure (stateful failover).

How do I achieve this ? Can conntrack tools help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless all your internal network computers have public IP addresses.

This is because your router is performing NAT from private address to its public address. Every outgoing link has an individual public IP address, and the other endpoint for the connection sees only that IP address.

So, when the link goes down, that public IP address cannot be used anymore. So, the connection must be set up again with another outgoing connection's IP address.

In the unlikely case that all your computers have public IP addresses, then routing protocols would take care that the traffic would be routed via the new links.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I was thinking on those lines too. Cant I keep one of the interfaces as a spare one , and in case any of the other active links fail I simply assign its IP to the spare one? Wont I get uninterrupted connections then?

Comment: If that spare interface is connected to the same IP network as any of the other interfaces is. However, if your network topology is like this, there is no benefit on having multiple outgoing links in the first place.

Comment: Yes I agree. Having a spare interface is of no use.

Comment: So can we safely conclude that automatic failover is not possible ?  All I can do is remove the failed interface IP from the routing table and re-establish connections all over again so they get routed through the active one and that would define fail over,  isnt it?

Comment: Yes, automatic failover while preserving connection state is not possible, if the router does NAT.

Comment: Fine, lets keep it at that for now. In case I come up with something new ill get back to you. Thanks for your answers, really helped. :)